# documentbuilderfactory not workining in android 3.0

Tags: android, xml, android-3.0-honeycomb

This is the code which I was using for android 2.3 . and it use to work properly.
But don no why it doesn't seem to work in android 3.0

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {

            try
            {
            while(this.xml.available()>0)
            Log.e("content", ""+this.xml.read());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("error", "while reading the file");
            }
            this.xml.reset();

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.xml);
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            Log.d(TAG, "have root?"+dom.getLocalName());;
            Log.d(TAG, "have root?"+dom.getInputEncoding());;
            Log.d(TAG, "have root?"+dom.getNodeValue());;
 }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        //Log.d(TAG, "Exit:  parse");
        return stores;
    }
```

The innner while displays the file contents in numbers.
But when I get the dom.* I get null why is it so ?

Any suggetions ?

Comment: root.getTagName() returns the proper head tag.. but when I try NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("somenode"); I always get nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the way the element are accessed are a bit different now.

For others check out the new ways of writing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually there were some bugs in DOM for android releases before Android 3.0
These bugs are corrected in 3.0 so there might be some changes required in the older implementations done by you using DOM

please refer to this link

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2735#c11

Cheers
HImanshu

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(stream);

NodeList nodeResponse = dom.getElementsByTagName("rootelement");
```